# Handling 404's with Named Location in Nginx and returning custom 404's

Tags: php, nginx, error-handling, url-rewriting

I have a web service which serves dynamic images via Nginx web server.

Requests are handled by interpreting the URL structure and passing the initial 404 response to a Named Location which then matches the URL to various conditions to return an appropriate image.

Here is the basic config:

```
error_page 404 = @imageHandlers;

location @imageHandlers {
  #= Match pattern 1 =========
  if ($uri ~* "^/(some_pattern1)$") {
    set $x = $1;
    rewrite .* "image_handler_type1.php?q=$x" last;
  }

  #= Match pattern 2 =========
  if ($uri ~* "^/(some_pattern2)$") {
    set $x = $1;
    rewrite .* "image_handler_type2.php?q=$x" last;
  }

  etc....
}
```

This works fine, but I also want to display custom 404 error page when non of the patterns are matched.

I thought I could handle this in my "custom_error.php" file:

```
<?php
$status = $_GET["status"];
if ($status == 404) {
  header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
}
?>
<html>
<head><title><?php echo $status;?></title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>Error <?php echo $status;?></h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

So that the Nginx config now looks like this:

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

error_page 404 = @imageHandlers;

location @imageHandlers {
  #= Match pattern 1 =========
  if ($uri ~* "^/(some_pattern1)$") {
    set $x = $1;
    rewrite .* "image_handler_type1.php?q=$x" last;
  }

  #= Match pattern 2 =========
  if ($uri ~* "^/(some_pattern2)$") {
    set $x = $1;
    rewrite .* "image_handler_type2.php?q=$x" last;
  }

  etc....

  #= Otherwise display custom 404 =========
  rewrite .* "/custom_error.php?status=404" last;
}
```

I added "fastcgi_intercept_errors on" so that Nginx does not intercept response codes greater than 300.

Unfortunately, the 404 response return by "custom_error.php" is still intercepted by Nginx and returns it's own standard 404 response because, I guess, the "@imageHandlers" Named Location pass resets the initial 404 back to status 200 inside the block.

If I comment out the "if ($status == 404)" block from "custom_error.php", the custom error display fine BUT I get the status 200 status response code which is not correct.

How can I achieve the custom 404 with the config I already set up?

Answer (score 0):

Having recently faced a problem with custom errors from within a named location and stumbled upon this question.

I think what is happening here is that when you reply with a 404, the `fastcgi_intercept_errors on` intercepts it, and you have a `error_page 404` defined, possibly leading to a potential recursion. In this case nginx will return its internal error.

I think you should not use `fastcgi_intercept_errors`, or alternatively you could define a different custom error in the @imageHandlers location, e.g. one that is not used (`error_page 417 /some_file.html`), so you stop inheriting the error_page defined from outside the location.

In my case I had to add a `recursive_error_pages on;` too, and you might also need it, not sure.